# How to get array of child objects contained in a GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I have a `GameObject` in Unity that is supposed to serve as a container for some definitions.

[image: object explorer]

I'd like to access that object and retrieve the `Def` class instances (every object there is instance of `Def` general class).

So, if I have a `GameObject` instance, how can I retrieve all objects that are instances of specific class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `GameObject.GetComponents<Def>();` to retrieve all components of `Def` type in the `GameObject`. 
More info in the Unity Docs http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponents.html

Answer (score 0):

```
public Def[] defArray;
public Defs gameobject; ///if you want to access from another class assign this your Defs gameobject from inspector

defs = Defs.GetComponents<Def>();  ///if you want access from another game object
defs = gameObject.GetComponents<Def>();  ///if Defs is attached to this gameObject
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have a `GameObject` reference you can use [**GetComponents()**](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponents.html).

```
Def [] list = gameObject.GetComponents<Def>();
```